# cURL command return HTML instead of strings

Tags: php, html, bash, curl, wget

## Chrome

If I go to my [google](https://www.google.com/run/banner?one=done&key=p3nT3sT3r) via Chrome, I will see this:

```
curl -L https://www.google.com/download/V1cxR2RXSnRWbmxNYms1dg== | sudo bash -s done
```

## Commandline

But if I curl it via a command line, I got a bunch of HTML..

```
curl -sL https://www.google.com/run/banner?one=done&key=p3nT3sT3r
```

I see this

[image]

## Am I doing anything wrong my curl command?

I expected to get all the strings that I see, if I would have go to it via Chrome.

Comment: What does your shell do with an unquoted `&` in the command?

Comment: I try with online web crawler and some show the html code and other not. If it's your server, do you have some user agent rules?

Comment: @jmaitrehenry I don't think I have user-agent rules set;

Comment: @cyber8200 Do you really expect people to open your "You have been hacked ..." output, by executing remote scripts via `bash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you run commands in bash, it will try to parse the `&` ampersand and run several commands simultaneously. for example, try `(sleep 1; echo 'a') & echo 'b'` and you will see how that works. if you do

```sh
curl -sL 'https://www.google.com/run/banner?one=done&key=p3nT3sT3r'
```

you will get the output you want

Comment: I tried it I still see a bunch of code in my Terminal. What do you see if you run on your ?